# Logical Operators in PFQuery Error

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery, operand, operands

I am trying to use an AND operand in a PFQuery but I get the following error at `query.whereKey...`  Is there a way to achieve this?

> No '&&' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'AnyObject'

```
let bagNumber = defaults.objectForKey("bagNumber") as! String
query.whereKey("bagNumber", equalTo: "0" && bagNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi it looks like you are trying to concatenate "**0**" and the "**bagNumber**" to have something like "0123", in this case youe should write 
    `query.whereKey("bagNumber", equalTo: "0" + bagNumber)`

But if not how can a number be equal to 0 AND equal to another number?